# Option Inspector -- option definitions

Tags: formatting

Relatively new to Mathematica, using v. 8.0.4.0 on OSX, and wanting to know where I can find something like a list of definitions for each of the many Global, Notebook, Cell, etc. options listed in the OptionsInspector.  Some are fairly obvious, and I've come across the definitions of several others in my learning a little about the system.  But I'd like to know how I can get the definition of any option in which I'm interested (at least a description of what that option does).  If you know of such a source, I would appreciate you pointing it up to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The following code prints the information for all of the options of `Cell`

```
Information /@ Options[Cell][[All,1]]
```

The usage messages could be obtained with

```
Message[#1::usage] & /@ Options[Cell][[All,1]]
```

---

The above will be too much information at once. Instead, use `Options[Cell]`, select from the output that option that seems to do what you need, press `F1`.

Comment: I edited because the use of `Map` to extract all first elements was unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: Thanks!