# What is a full list of cell styling options and sub-options?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, cells

I'm trying to customize a style sheet and have hit a few speed bumps and walls.

Firstly, I can't see how to do a few specific things, like to set the color of the cell's left side label:

[image]

Or how to set cursor color:

[image]

And sometimes cell font's are not being set according to the style I'm providing (even though the font is correctly named and installed on my machine) like this:

[image]

***What is a full list of cell styling options and suboptions?*** Is there a visual guide somewhere?

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
     (*PrivateCellOptions\[Rule]{},*)

     CellBracketOptions -> {"Color" -> RGBColor[0, 0.79, 0.82], 
       "HoverColor" -> RGBColor[0, 0.59, 0.12]}, 
     AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.9, 0.83, 0.52, 0.74], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
         ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False}, 
       "ExcessArgumentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8627450980392157, 0.19607843137254902`, 
           0.1843137254901961]}, 
       "FunctionLocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.65, 0.89, 0.18], 
         FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}}, 
       "GraphicsCompatibilityProblemStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8627450980392157, 0.19607843137254902`, 
           0.1843137254901961]}, 
       "LocalScopeConflictStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8274509803921568, 0.21176470588235294`, 
           0.5098039215686274]}, 
       "LocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[1., 0.91, 0.57]}, 
       "MissingArgumentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8627450980392157, 0.19607843137254902`, 
           0.1843137254901961]}, 
       "MisspelledWordStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8274509803921568, 0.21176470588235294`, 
           0.5098039215686274]}, 
       "NoKernelPresentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.16470588235294117`, 0.6313725490196078, 
           0.596078431372549]}, 
       "PatternVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.65, 0.89, 0.18], FontSlant -> "Italic"}, 
       "StringStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[0.99, 0.59, 0.12], 
         ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
         AutoNumberFormatting -> False}, 
       "SymbolContextStyles" -> {"System`" -> {RGBColor[0.4, 0.85, 
            0.94]}, "Global`" -> {RGBColor[0.98, 0.15, 0.45]}, 
         Automatic -> {}}, 
       "UndefinedSymbolStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.68, 0.51, 1.]}, 
       "UnknownOptionStyle" -> {FontColor -> 

          RGBColor[0.8627450980392157, 0.19607843137254902`, 
           0.1843137254901961]}, 
       "UnwantedAssignmentStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
          RGBColor[0.8627450980392157, 0.19607843137254902`, 
           0.1843137254901961]}}, 
     CodeAssistOptions -> {"HeadHighlightStyle" -> {Background -> 
          RGBColor[0.29, 0.28, 0.24], 
         FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}}, 
       "MatchHighlightStyle" -> {Background -> 
          RGBColor[0.29, 0.28, 0.24]}}, StyleMenuListing -> None, 
     FontColor -> RGBColor[0.81, 0.81, 0.76], 
     Background -> RGBColor[0.15, 0.16, 0.13]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], CellFrame -> {{1.5, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
     CellGroupingRules -> {GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}, 
     CellFrameMargins -> {{16, 8}, {8, 8}}, 
     CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.68, 0.51, 1.], 
     FontFamily -> "Consolas", FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> "Plain", 
     FontSlant -> "Plain", FontTracking -> "Plain", 
     FontVariations -> {"Outline" -> False, "Shadow" -> False, 
       "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.7], 
     Background -> RGBColor[0.08, 0.16, 0.16]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Output"], CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
     CellGroupingRules -> {GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}, 
     CellFrameMargins -> {{16, 8}, {8, 8}}, 
     CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.98, 0.15, 0.45], 
     Background -> RGBColor[0.13, 0.13, 0.09], 
     "ContentAreaBackground" -> RGBColor[0.13, 0.13, 0.09]],
    Cell[StyleData["Message"], 
     FontColor -> 
      RGBColor[0.704600595101854, 0.24277103837644007`, 
       0.22278171969176777`]],
    Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], FontFamily -> "Consolas", 
     FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSlant -> "Plain", 
     FontTracking -> "Plain", 
     FontVariations -> {"Outline" -> False, "Shadow" -> False, 
       "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}], 
    Cell[StyleData["MSG"], MenuSortingValue -> 10000, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]], 
    Cell[StyleData["CellExpression"], MenuSortingValue -> 10000, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[1], Background -> GrayLevel[0]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Button"], MenuSortingValue -> 10000, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]],
    Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontFamily -> "Arkitech Light", 
     FontSize -> 20, FontWeight -> "Thin", 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.88]],
    Cell[StyleData["Code"], FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16, 
     CellFrameMargins -> 16, CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
     CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.84, 0.36, 0.76], 
     FontSlant -> "Plain", 
     FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> False, 
       "Underline" -> False},
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[1], Background -> GrayLevel[0.11]]
    }]
 ]
```

Note: I'm setting the styles from within the notebook because otherwise I get into this situation where I can't see anything:

[image]

Comment: Related: [(34301)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34301/142) shows a way to get all `Cell` option names (and any available usage information).  The same trick works for each of `Options /@ {$FrontEnd, $FrontEndSession, Notebook}`.  [(71301)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71301/142) shows ways to compute effective sets of styling options.